# How to select node agent depending on os.name

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have master and slave jenkins nodes, some are linux os,some are windows os .
I have a jenkins pipeline stage that can only run in windows node.

How to force the jenkins pipeline to select only slaves available agent that are windows slaves nodes ?

Comment: you can use labels then in your declarative pipeline: agent { label 'windows' }

Comment: This helped.thanks, please provide it as answer

Comment: Posted, thanks @sancelot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that would be label your node and then use them in the agents part of your declarative pipeline:

```
agent { label 'windows' }
```